# How to make a clear date display on the axis (Altair)?

Tags: python, plot, altair

My code

```
total_cases_graph = alt.Chart(subset_data).transform_filter(
    alt.datum.confirmed > 0
).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', type='nominal', title='Date'),
    y=alt.Y('sum(confirmed):Q',  title='Confirmed cases'),
    color='region_name',
    tooltip='sum(confirmed)',
).properties(
    width=1000,
    height=500
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=17,
    titleFontSize=20
)
```

Now it is displayed like this

[image]

I would like the dates to be less frequent, i.e. some dates were displayed at intervals

Comment: It's likely because you have set the type to 'nominal', try just `x=alt.X('date:T', title='Date')`. If that doesn't work, please upload a sample of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Work

```
    total_cases_graph = alt.Chart(subset_data).transform_filter(
        size
    ).mark_line().encode(
        x=alt.X('date:T', type='temporal', title='Date'),
        y=alt.Y('sum(' + type + '):Q',  title=type_title),
        color='region_name',
        tooltip='sum(' + type + ')',
    ).properties(
        width=1000,
        height=500
    ).configure_axis(
        labelFontSize=17,
        titleFontSize=20
    )
```